# virtuemart child products in select?

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

i want to setup a product sub product structure on a VM site - can you tell me if its possible

at the moment i have products and sub products setup but in this instance VM shows all the products in the related category - this i do not want - i would like to see only the parent products and then have all the children in a select element on the parent product page  just like this : [image: http://screencast.com/t/G50cMYo187X8]

can this be done in VIRTUEMART ?

thanks !

tnx

Comment: anyone - virtuemart possible of this ?

Comment: "Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved." => Yep, '-1' on a few of their (@OP's) Qt's because they never reacted/followed up and even less accepted any of the many Answers they got, and all this SINCE 2015...! All 5 years...!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about virtuemart can do it but you can use redSHOP http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/redshop

Comment: thanks - but id rather go with a tried and tested product - that redshop has only one review !

Comment: Not true. There might be a bug in JED. redSHOP is 6 years old Joomla! E-commerce MVC Extension. Since 1.5. http://redcomponent.com/redshop

Answer (score 1):

Remove the child products from the categories. Only the parent product should have a category.